# Commutation relationship of the generator of SO(N)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics

The group $S O(N)$ is defined as the set of $N \times N$ matrices $R_{i j}$ that leave the $N$-dimensional Euclidean metric invariant, i.e.,
$$
\delta_{i j}=R_{i k} R_{j l} \delta_{k l},$$
which also has the determinant of 1.

Consider representing $S O(N)$ by unitary matrices $U(R)$. Show that the generators of the $S O(N)$ group satisfy the commutation relations
$$
\left[J^{i j}, J^{k l}\right]=\frac{1}{2} i\left(\delta^{i l} J^{j k}-\delta^{j l} J^{i k}-\delta^{k i} J^{j l}+\delta^{k j} J^{i l}\right)
$$

To show this, write an infinitesimal $S O(N)$ transformation as $U(R)=1+i \omega_{i j} J^{i j}$, where $J^{i j}=-J^{j i}$ and $\omega_{i j}=-\omega_{ji}$. Use the fact that, $U(R) U(1+\omega) U(R)^{-1}=U\left(R(1+\omega) R^{-1}\right)$
(Hint: Use infinitesimal $R_{i j}=\delta_{i j}+\omega_{i j}$)

---

My attempt: I have used the fact of $U(R) U(1+\omega) U(R)^{-1}=U\left(R(1+\omega) R^{-1}\right)$ to get $U(R) J^{l k} U^{+}(R)=R_{i l} R_{j k} J^{i k}$ and I plugged in $U(R)=1+i \omega_{i j} J^{i j}$ and $R_{i j}=\delta_{i j}+\omega_{i j}$ and by doing the procedure twice and using the fact that $\omega$ is antisymmetric, I was able to get:
$$
\omega_{i j}\left[J^{i j}, J^{l k}\right]=\frac{i}{2}\left[w_{j l} J^{j k}+w_{i l} J^{i k}+w_{k j} J^{j l}+w_{k i} J^{i l}\right]
$$.

**I am not sure this equation is correct** but I feel like I am really close if miraculously $\frac{\omega_{jl}}{\omega{ij}} = \delta_{jl}$. I can't find any reason for this to be true though. Any insights will be greatly appreciated!

*Apologies if the question is framed improperly, please point out and I can make improvements to the question.*

Comment: [$SO(N)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Special_orthogonal_group) is the subgroup of all orthogonal $N\times N$ matrices with determinant one. How does your first equation reflect this? And how do we represent $SO(N)$ by unitary matrices? I stopped reading there.

Comment: @OrionPax: The definition you've given in the first sentence seems to me to characterize $O(n)$ rather than $SO(n)$. For instance, the matrix $\pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$ seems to have the required property, but it's not in $SO(2)$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Correct. I edited the comment and put in "orthogonal".

Comment: @JohnHughes I am sorry, I really don't know math that well, this is an assignment problem from my physics class :( But I just read form Wikipedia, isn't SO(N) just O(N) with an identity?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that's not the correct description of $SO(n)$.  $SO(n)$ is the subset of $O(n)$ consisting of matrices with determinant $+1$ rather than $-1$.

Comment: @OrionPax What you are thinking of there is that $SO(n)$ is the connected component of the identity in $O(n)$. That is, it is a subset of $O(n)$ comprising all elements connected (by a path in $O(n)$, say) to the identity $I \in O(n)$